# iOS Simulator appears half of desired size

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

Not sure what happened, but I recently updated Xcode 6, and now the iOS Simulator contents does not fill the whole screen.  And yes, I checked window -> scale options.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click **iOS Simulator** in the menu bar, then select **Reset Content and Settings**. I often find that when I update Xcode this is a good idea as problems like yours arise.